# What is difference between kbd and code tags?

Tags: html

I don't think it is possible that HTML5 specifications introduce repeated tags that do the same thing. I need, exactly, what is the **practically** and **hypothetically** difference between both `<kbd>` and `<code>` tags?

This **[demo](http://jsbin.com/yefeboso/2/)** shows that they have the same effect!

Comment: Try the `<kbd>` tag in the editor here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code

Comment: @Mat Sure, I tried it and I found that it is styled. However, `code` tag could be styled too.

Comment: Yes, and `<span>` can be styled too, and all the others. I don't really see what you're getting at. They're supposed to have different semantics, that's all.

Comment: @Mat No, but `span` does not change some characteristics by default.

Comment: Ok. `ul/li` then, they "change some characteristics by default".

Comment: @mat So what your problem here? Without CSS, unordered lists or ordered lists make something visually different. Please get a look at the demo I supplied in the question to get more in touch with what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not clear what exactly you are asking about, however, you can find all the differences and similarities in the HTML5 spec. For example:

#### Meaning

The [`kbd` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element)

> represents user input […]

The [`code` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/rendering.html#phrasing-content-0)

> represents a fragment of computer code […]

#### Content model, attributes etc.

The same. Both are *flow content* / *phrasing content* / *palpable content*. Both have the *phrasing content* content model. Both can only have the global attributes, same ARIA roles etc.

#### Styling

They have the same [default styling](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/rendering.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints):

> ```
> code, kbd, samp, tt { font-family: monospace; }
> ```

Comment: Well, to make my question clear, I have asked for **hypothetical** purpose of introducing two or more tags do the same thing. In other words, what is the difference in the usability of a HTML document between using the two tags? or Why should I decide to use `kbd` instead of `code` or vice versa?

Comment: @sємsєм: Well, then the "Meaning" section of my answer applies: These two elements have a different meaning, they are used for different things. But this is obvious, isn’t it? -- They don’t "do" something per se, or in other words, it depends on the user-agents if or what they do with these elements.

Comment: I think like that because I don't know what could I gain or loss if mistakenly/correctly chose one of them instead of the other. In usability they are identical.

Comment: @sємsєм: Well, then you would have incorrect HTML5. As a result of that, it *may* happen that your page breaks for user-agents that use/interpret your `kbd` and/or `code` markup in some way.

Comment: @unor could you give some examples of the way user agents treat `kbd` and `code` differently?

Answer (score 4):

Both are displayed the same by DEFAULT, unless additional styling is put in place.   However, they have different uses:

`<kbd>` should be used for keyboard and user commands

`<code>` should be used for displaying blocks of code

### References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd

Comment: "Both are displayed the same by DEFAULT" do all user agents do that?

Comment: @PeeHaa I would think so, as long as all browsers follow the specification correctly.   Basically, each is displayed in a system font by default.

Comment: I don't see anything in the spec about styling?

Comment: Right, it's up to the web dev to decide what styling is needed, if any.   The browser will apply a default styling to each, which is normally a mono-spaced system looking font.

Comment: @Charlie74: `kbd` is not only for *keyboard* input, it is for user input in general. (See also this [meta-discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215133/193139) about its use here on Stack Exchange)

Comment: @unor that's a good point, thanks...  I generally think of it is keyboard commands, but the spec does specify `user input`.